# Talend query data in mysql based on inputs from hive

Tags: mysql, hive, talend

I have a requirement to query a column in Hive and based on the output I want to query it in MySQL DB.

The flow is something like below:

1. Query Hive table, get the list of IDs
2. Use the list of ID's to query MySQL table. The query would be like `select a,b,c from x where id in (list from hive)`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make your query using a tHiveInput component to retrieve the Id's and then you've got two options, the easy way or the hard (and better) way:

For the easy way you can then run from the tHiveInput component to a tFlowToIterate and then iterate out to a tMySqlInput component. Your query in the tMySqlInput component would then look something like:

```
"SELECT a, b, c
FROM x
WHERE id = '" + ((Integer)globalMap.get("row1.id")) + "'"
```

row1 here represents the row running into your tFlowToIterate. You can also get this variable by hitting ctrl+space and selecting the `tFlowToIterate_x.id` option.

You could then connect a tBufferOutput component to your tMySqlInput component to collect all of the iterations and then read it back in with a tBufferInput component for further processing.

This is obviously a simple concatenation that is then not the best way for efficiency and of course open to SQL injection. But it's a rough and ready way.

Your other (harder but potentially better) option is to use a parameterised query using a tMySqlRow component (not currently supported in the tMySqlInput component as of Talend 5.4).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085127/2291321) goes into some detail about parameterised queries in Talend as part of a solution to another problem (upserting efficiently). As mentioned in that answer, there's more detail on parameterised queries on [Gabriele Baldassarre's blog](http://gabrielebaldassarre.com/2014/03/16/using-rdbms-prepared-statements-increase-efficiency-security-talend-queries/).

Comment: Thank you Sir. But I found a better way, we can use something like group_concat to get the inlist value as a single value. Assign the value to a parameter and then use the context parameter in the mysql query. :)